# How does DNA damage increase the activity of p53?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I understand the steps leading up to the halting of the S-cdK checkpoint from there, but I can't find the mechanism by which DNA damage actually increases the activity of p53.

Comment: p53 is expressed constitutively but, in unstressed cells, it is an inactive conformation and its level is kept low by proteasomal degradation. Proteins which are recruited to double strand breaks can start a signalling cascade of protein kinases which leads to 1) stabilization of p53 and 2) activation by phosphorylation. If I find the time, I'll try and write a proper answer.